# Using sort in XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to sort a differents values but I can't make it functional.

My example XML:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="7.xsl"?>
<immobles>
    <ofertes>
        <oferta estat="1">Venda</oferta>
        <oferta estat="2">Lloguer</oferta>
    </ofertes>

    <categories>
        <categoria cat="A">Pis</categoria>
        <categoria cat="B">Casa</categoria>
        <categoria cat="C">Duplex</categoria>
    </categories>

    <propietaris>
        <propietari dni="400001">Fernando</propietari>
        <propietari dni="400004">Berta</propietari>
        <propietari dni="400002">Judit</propietari>
        <propietari dni="400007">Manel</propietari>
        <propietari dni="400003">Pilar</propietari>
        <propietari dni="400005">Jordi</propietari>     
    </propietaris>

    <immobiliaries>
        <immobiliaria codi="I1">Home sweet home</immobiliaria>
        <immobiliaria codi="I2">Com a casa enlloc</immobiliaria>
        <immobiliaria codi="I3">Llar de foc</immobiliaria>
        <immobiliaria codi="I4">Pisos penyasegat</immobiliaria>
    </immobiliaries>

    <propietats>
        <propietat id="1" oferta="1" propietari="400003">
            <nom>Pis a l'eixample</nom>
            <categoria cat="A"/>
            <valorat>145000</valorat>
            <preu>520</preu>
            <companyies>
                <companyia comp="I3" />
                <companyia comp="I4" />
            </companyies>
        </propietat>

        <propietat id="2" oferta="2" propietari="400001">
            <nom>Casa moderna 4 habitacions</nom>
            <categoria cat="B"/>
            <valorat>358000</valorat>
            <preu>350000</preu>
            <companyies>
                <companyia comp="I2" />
                <companyia comp="I3" />
            </companyies>
        </propietat>

        <propietat id="3" oferta="2" propietari="400002">
            <nom>Duplex emmoblat lluminós</nom>
            <categoria cat="C"/>
            <valorat>210000</valorat>
            <preu>150000</preu>
            <companyies>
                <companyia comp="I1" />
            </companyies>
        </propietat>

        <propietat id="3" oferta="1" propietari="400005">
            <nom>Duplex centre</nom>
            <categoria cat="C"/>
            <valorat>160000</valorat>
            <preu>340</preu>
            <companyies>
                <companyia comp="I4" />
                <companyia comp="I1" />
            </companyies>
        </propietat>

    </propietats>
</immobles>
```

My XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th>Propietat en lloguer</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="//propietat">
        <xsl:variable name="idofer" select="@oferta" />
        <xsl:variable name="idcat" select="categoria/@cat" />
        <xsl:variable name="idpropi" select="@propietari" />
        <xsl:variable name="propiofer" select="//ofertes/oferta[@estat=$idofer]" />
        <xsl:variable name="propicat" select="//categories/categoria[@cat=$idcat]" />
        <xsl:variable name="propipropieari" select="//propietaris/propietari[@dni=$idpropi]" />
        <tr>
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="$propiofer='Lloguer'">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="nom">
              <xsl:sort select="preu" order="ascending" />
              <xsl:sort select="$propicat" order="descending" />
              <xsl:sort select="$propipropietari" order="descending" />
            </xsl:apply-templates>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I need to show the values that are in "Lloguer" `ofertes/oferta`, and order by them for `preu`, `categories/categoria` and `propietaris/propietari`.

I'm not sure of if I need to use apply-template or if I can make it from another way

Comment: Can you please show the output you expect in this case? Thank you!

Comment: The idea was to get the elements from `propietat/nom`, `categories/categoria` and `propietaris/propietari`. I understand that I have expressed badly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, consider using a key to look up your `oferta` elements.

```
<xsl:key name="ofertes" match="oferta" use="@estat" />
```

Then, to select only `propietat` which have an `oferta` of "Lloguer", you can do this....

```
<xsl:for-each select="//propietat[key('ofertes', @oferta)='Lloguer']">
```

You can also use keys in your sort. So, to sort by the `categoria` value, you would define a key like so

```
<xsl:key name="categories" match="categoria" use="@cat" />
```

Then, you can use it in the sort like so...

```
  <xsl:for-each select="//propietat[key('ofertes', @oferta)='Lloguer']">
    <xsl:sort select="preu" order="ascending" />
    <xsl:sort select="key('categories', categoria/@cat)" order="descending" />
```

Try this XSLT for starters...

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:key name="ofertes" match="oferta" use="@estat" />
  <xsl:key name="categories" match="categoria" use="@cat" />
  <xsl:key name="propietaris" match="propietari" use="@dni" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th>Propietat en lloguer</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="//propietat[key('ofertes', @oferta)='Lloguer']">
        <xsl:sort select="preu" order="ascending" />
        <xsl:sort select="key('categories', categoria/@cat)" order="descending" />
        <xsl:sort select="key('propietaris', @propietari)" order="descending" />
        <tr>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="nom" /></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="key('categories', categoria/@cat)" /></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="key('propietaris', @propietari)" /></td>
        </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Your options looks nice, but what is the exact function of the keys? Sorry about that, I'm starting

Comment: Keys enable you to look up other values from the XML much more efficiently. Read up about them here https://www.xml.com/pub/a/2002/02/06/key-lookups.html